# Map key of object with array of object value

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have an array of object as:

```
const bookDetails = [{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":"121"}, 
                 {"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":908}, 
                 {"author":"romero","email":"alpha@gmail.com","readingTime":1212},
                 {"author":"buck","email":"buck@gmail.com","readingTime":1902}, 
                 {"author":"buck","email":"bujor@gmail.com","readingTime":12125}, 
                 {"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":500},
                 {"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":10},
                 {"author":"legend","email":"legend@gmail.com","readingTime":12}
                 {"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":1890}]
```

I have an object as:
const toMatch = {"romero@gmail.com":1212,"john@gmail.com":1248,"bujor@gmail.com":909}

I want to replace emailId with corresponding author.

**So my expected O/P should be: {"romero":1212,"john":1248,"buck":909}**

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: Ah, you want to matching names from emails based on the array of objects. Is that right? If so I have an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a new object by iterating over `bookDetails` and look up the values from `toMatch`

Like this

```js
const bookDetails=[{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":"121"},{"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":908},{"author":"romero","email":"alpha@gmail.com","readingTime":1212},{"author":"buck","email":"buck@gmail.com","readingTime":1902},{"author":"buck","email":"bujor@gmail.com","readingTime":12125},{"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":500},{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":10},{"author":"legend","email":"legend@gmail.com","readingTime":12},{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":1890}]
const toMatch = {"romero@gmail.com":1212,"john@gmail.com":1248,"bujor@gmail.com":909}

const result = {};

for (const detail of bookDetails) {
    const {email, author} = detail;
    if (email in toMatch) {
        result[author] = toMatch[email];
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This was really helpful. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

There you go, I'm 100% you can do this easier, but this is the fastest response that came to my mind:

```
function changeData(bookDetails){
    let returnableObject = {};
    bookDetails.forEach(book => {
        returnableObject[book.author] = book.readingTime
})
return returnableObject;
}
```

*EDIT -> This would work if your Author name IS UNIQUE if the author name is not unique you should change the name or maybe use an array of objects, not an object with multiple values...

*EDIT 2 -> I think I didnt understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you want to matching names from emails based on the array of objects. Is that right? If so..

```js
const bookDetails=[{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":"121"},{"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":908},{"author":"romero","email":"alpha@gmail.com","readingTime":1212},{"author":"buck","email":"buck@gmail.com","readingTime":1902},{"author":"buck","email":"bujor@gmail.com","readingTime":12125},{"author":"romero","email":"romero@gmail.com","readingTime":500},{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":10},{"author":"legend","email":"legend@gmail.com","readingTime":12},{"author":"john","email":"john@gmail.com","readingTime":1890}]

function namesMap(object,list){
  //to save complexity(assuming the array is huge), I'd just loop through the list once to get the data I need
  var obj={} //relates emails to names
  list.forEach(item=>{
    obj[item.email]=item.author
  })
  var toReturn={}
  Object.keys(object).forEach(email=>{
    toReturn[obj[email]]=object[email] //email to name conversion
  })
  return toReturn
}

//example usage
const toMatch = {"romero@gmail.com":1212,"john@gmail.com":1248,"bujor@gmail.com":909}
console.log(namesMap(toMatch,bookDetails))
```